# When i restore database in db2 got an exception "SQL1092N Mahesh does not have the authority to perform the requested command"

Tags: sql, db2

When I restoring database in db2

### Got an exception:

SQL1092N  Mahesh does not have the authority to perform the requested command

what we have to do.

Comment: Talk to your DBA and get the proper "authority" to do this work.

Comment: I didn't understand i didn't connect to DB,directly running this command

Comment: I don't' have this user in my DB "Mahesh",I am logging the system using this id

Answer (score 0):

The user does not have the necessary privileges.

> To grant privileges on most database objects, you must have ACCESSCTRL
>   authority, SECADM authority, or CONTROL privilege on that object; or,
>   you must hold the privilege WITH GRANT OPTION. Additionally, users
>   with SYSADM or SYSCTRL authority can grant table space privileges. You
>   can grant privileges only on existing objects.

[Source](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0005804.html).

Comment: I don't' have this user in my DB "Mahesh",I am logging the system using this id

Comment: @mahesh, you have an SQL error, therefore the problem is on DB level.

Comment: can i do this one

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTBX_8.5.7/com.ibm.wbpm.admin.doc/topics/rins_trbl_domain_userid.html

Comment: @mahesh, this should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get around authority issues restoring a database.  Restore the database to a test library.  Then copy the database.